# How can i zoom in to a raycaster selection?

Tags: three.js

I wonder how can i zoom in to mouse selection with ThreeJs, i'm using raycaster for selecting the model areas but something isn't working when i click on areas - as you can see in [My Example](https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/g49t8j0s/54/) (thanks to Mugen87) , my goal is to zoom into faces when i click on them... i've added the following function :

```
function onClick(event) {
 
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( mesh, false, intersects );
  if(mesh.type!= 'Mesh' ||  !intersects.length){
  return
  }

    var n = intersects[ 0 ].face.normal.clone();
    n.multiplyScalar(30);
    n.add(intersects[ 0 ].point);
    var p = intersects[ 0 ].point;
    camera.position.copy(n);
    camera.lookAt(p);
    
 
}
```

When i click outside the model - it's not keeping the position and it's spinning ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using `OrbitControls`, which pretty much takes over your camera and assigns its position and rotation once per frame. When you try to set its position manually, `OrbitControls` overrides anything you did.

The solution is to make your `controls` variable global. Then when you're ready to take over the camera position, set `controls.enabled = false;` in the `onClick()` function. Then when you're ready to return to the regular controls, set `controls.enabled = true;`

https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.enabled